# can't preserve null value in php form updating multiple rows

Tags: php, forms, null, edit

I have a form that updates multiple rows. An item and the date is was completed. The default value of COMPLETED is null.  In php/mysql I have a form to edit the list.  I can update COMPLETED however if I do not enter a value in the form it does not remain NULL, it inserts a date of 0000-00-00. There functionality requires either a valid date or NULL. Here's the relevant code:

form:

```
echo '<form method="post">';            

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res) )
{   
    echo 'LIST_NUM : ' . $row["LIST_NUM"]. '<br/>';
    echo 'I did this : ' . $row["ITEM_NAME"]. '<br/>';
    echo 'on : <input type="text" name="COMPLETED['. $row["LIST_NUM"] .']" value='.$row["COMPLETED"].'><br/>'."\n";
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="LIST_NUM[]" value="'. $row["LIST_NUM"] .'">'."\n";
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="'. $row["LIST_NUM"] .'">'."\n";
    echo "<hr>\n";


}
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="make it so">';
echo '</form>';
```

---

Insert

```
foreach ( $_POST["LIST_NUM"] AS $LIST_NUM ) {

$ITEM_NAME =mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["ITEM_NAME"][$LIST_NUM]);
$COMPLETED = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["COMPLETED"][$LIST_NUM]);
$update = " UPDATE `UCKET`.`LIST` SET `COMPLETED` = '$COMPLETED' WHERE `LIST`.`LIST_NUM` =$LIST_NUM;";
mysql_query($update) or die( mysql_error());
```

the table allows NULL, it's the default setting for that field. My hunch is that the form field is passing something but I don't know how to allow it to pass a date if the user enters one while passing null if no value is entered in the form.

Thanks

Comment: **A:** Alter your column as NULL for its default value. You can also use a ternary operator in conjunction with the former. Or just a ternary operator if you cannot alter its current state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_real_escape_string() returns a string (or boolean if it errors), so your $COMPLETED variable becomes an empty string which is !== NULL. Furthermore, the variable type NULL in PHP will not translate properly to the evaluated string that is your query (especially since you have $COMPLETED quoted in your query). You will need to check to see if $COMPLETED is an empty string and handle things accordingly. Maybe like this:

```
if(empty($COMPLETED)) {
   $update = " UPDATE `UCKET`.`LIST` SET `COMPLETED` = NULL WHERE `LIST`.`LIST_NUM` =$LIST_NUM;";
} else {
   $update = " UPDATE `UCKET`.`LIST` SET `COMPLETED` = '$COMPLETED' WHERE `LIST`.`LIST_NUM` =$LIST_NUM;";
}
```

An alternative (and better) solution would be to use prepared statements so that you can pass your php variable of type null directly to the database for insertion rather than evaluating a NULL inside of a query string.

```
if(empty($COMPLETED)) {
   unset($COMPLETED);
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `UCKET`.`LIST` SET `COMPLETED` = ? WHERE `LIST`.`LIST_NUM` = ?;");

$stmt->bind_param('si', $COMPLETED, $LIST_NUM);
```

Using prepared statements eliminates the need for mysql_real_escape_string() since the variables are passed directly to the database server and handled as parameters for the query. It may be the case that you won't even need to unset($COMPLETED) if it is already null, but this depends on how your form is designed.

Comment: I'm glad that helped, and welcome to StackOverflow. If this answered your question completely, would you consider marking it as the answer to your question? Thanks!